# How do I drop a table by its Object Identifier (OID) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete a hidden table in PostgreSQL using it's OID say 16417. How do I do that?

I could see that the table exists by mapping the OID to the regclass using

```
SELECT 16417::regclass;
```

I got an output of

```
         regclass         
--------------------------
 cyanaudit.tb_audit_field
(1 row)
```

How do I drop this? I tried using `drop table cyanaudit.tb_audit_field;` but it did not work, giving the following message,

```
ERROR:  relation "cyanaudit.tb_audit_field" does not exist
LINE 1: ... distinct table_schema ) end                 from cyanaudit....
                                                             ^
QUERY:  select case when in_schema is not null then ARRAY[ in_schema ] else array_agg( distinct table_schema ) end                 from cyanaudit.tb_audit_field
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function cyanaudit.fn_update_audit_fields(character varying) line 1 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT cyanaudit.fn_update_audit_fields()"
PL/pgSQL function cyanaudit.fn_update_audit_fields_event_trigger() line 1 at PERFORM
```

Although it shows that the table does not exist, I still get

```
         regclass         
--------------------------
 cyanaudit.tb_audit_field
(1 row)
```

Whenever I query

```
SELECT 16417::regclass;
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an event trigger messed with your operation.

Event triggers run when DDL statements like `DROP TABLE` are executed.

In this case, it seems to be an event trigger running *after* the DDL operation.

The event trigger function tries to do something with the table that triggered it, but since you dropped that table, the function failed (that's probably a bug in the trigger function).

Since the event trigger failed, the whole transaction *including the `DROP TABLE`* was rolled back, so the table is not really deleted.

You will need to either disable or drop that event trigger or fix the trigger function so that you can drop the table.

Comment: How do I remove the triggers?
For example if my trigger is :
    tr_after_audit_field_change AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cyanaudit.tb_audit_field FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cyanaudit.fn_after_audit_field_change()

Comment: I removed the triggers still I am not able to remove the table

Comment: Regular DML triggers are not your problem. Use `\dy` in `psql` to see the event triggers. Your problem is the one with the trigger function `cyanaudit.fn_update_audit_fields_event_trigger()`.

Comment: Thanks this worked. You are a life saver. I disabled all triggers should I enable them again?

Comment: If you want them, sure. It is not for me to say.

Comment: When I go to execute my program again I get an error that cyanaudit.tb_audit_field does not exist. Should it not get generated on its own after first execution after deleting the file?

Comment: I don't understand. You dropped the table, now it is gone. Tables don't get created automatically. Execution of what? That looks like material for a different question.